# Keras/TF Recurrent Layers (GRU, LSTM) Freezing Kernel on Initialization

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

On my machine at home, I am running into a problem that does not occur on my work machine.  Specifically, Python freezes and locks up the kernel (which I can't even interrupt) on initializing a recurrent layer of moderate size.

A minimal reproducible example follows:

```
from keras.models import Model  # Keras 2.x
from keras.layers import Input, GRU
from keras import backend as K  # TensorFlow (1.3) backend

input_stuff = Input(shape=(1, 2048))  # Works
print(K.int_shape(input_stuff))  # Works
encoder = GRU(512, return_state=False, stateful=False)  # Works
gru_out = encoder(input_stuff)  # Freezes here
print(K.int_shape(gru_out))
```

The same thing happens when I try it with an LSTM instead of a GRU.  (Ignore if you will the apparent oddness of using a recurrent layer with input that has a single time step.)

When it freezes, it just runs forever.  (It *might* stop at some point, but I always kill everything before it does.)  The fan eventually groans as though it's doing some real work.  I notice no significant draw on available RAM.  I also noticed that TensorFlow by this point has allocated no memory on the GPU.  CPU load, on the other hand, shoots up to about 400% (this is an eight-core machine).

I recently installed TensorFlow 1.4 via pip, but this is loading 1.3 on a Python 3.6 kernel.  A few stray points:

- Initializing a *much* smaller layer (say, 20) with much smaller input works.  It doesn't take much more than that to kill it, though.
- The code that fails here works quickly and without issue in a Conda environment running Python 3.5.  It also works on my office computer using a similar (but not identical) package configuration.
- Configuration-wise, my home machine is at least as powerful as my work machine, so it's not a hardware issue (assuming the hardware is working properly).
- I was able to run other code to train a CNN without issue.  However, earlier code for a layered LSTM network that had worked fine on this machine now produces the same error described here.

**My suspicion is that this is a package/module or version conflict somehow.**  I admit that I have not been as careful as I should have been using separate environments instead of lumping everything together in my core Python build while sandboxing code.  I have a few conflicting versions of modules (some through pip and some through Conda) on my machine, so maybe this is me learning a lesson.

One "fix" is obviously to use the Conda environment in which this works without giving me any problems.  But this is such a bizarre symptom; I'd really like to understand *why* it's happening.

System info:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Memory: 31.4 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz × 8
- GPU: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

For package info (yikes), output of "conda list" is [here](https://pastebin.com/YpcZ0A0G).

Comment: Uninstalling the Conda versions of Keras and TensorFlow and reinstalling using native pip *seems* to have worked.  I'm getting a 3.5 vs 3.6 compiletime/runtime warning on import, but I'm no longer getting the problem above.  For the moment.  If this holds up, I'll update as an answer.

Comment: Hi Romann, in 2019, with a similar Memory RAM, Intel i7 and GeForce 1080 Ti and ubuntu 18.04 I have the same problem. Could you understand the cause of this problem?

Comment: It's been a while since this happened, so some details have been lost to time.  But it was apparently some sort of a conflict between the versions of TensorFlow and Keras that I had installed in my base environment at that time.  (It worked in a Conda virtual environment but not in the base, for instance.)  An uninstall of the Conda versions and reinstalling via pip fixed it for me in this case, as this removed the conflict.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for the feedback, I will investigate.